# Select a radio input when the row is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, row

I need to have a radio input selected when a user clicks anywhere in the row and highlight the row when the mouse goes trough it. I have been toying with some options but cannot get anything to work apart of those with jquery/javascript, but I'm sure there's some way to make it work with plain html/css.

I know that can be done toying with label+inputs plus "tables" or "display:table-row;" or  widths but I 'm just not able to make it work.
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it after hours of reading and testing. Here you have even IE8+ compatible, works for input radio and checkboxes. You can change the width and the colours as you need. The CSS:

```
.div-table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.div-table-row{
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    clear:both;
}
.div-table-row:hover{
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.div-table-col>input{
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;
    width: 6%;
    outline: none !important;
}
.div-table-col>label{
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;
    width: 94%;
}
.div-table-col>input:checked + label{
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this(add as many rows as you need):

```
<form action="" class="div-table">
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">
        <input type="radio" name="nametest" id="t1" value="1">
        <label for="t1"> Blablabla</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">
        <input type="radio" name="nametest" id="t2" value="2">
        <label for="t2"> Blablabla Blablabla Blablabla Blablabla</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css on your `tr`to get the hover effect like:

```
ROW_CLASS:hover{
    background-color: COLOR
}
```

And then add a click event handler on all `tr` with or without a class in jquery like:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).find("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: As I said "I have been toying with some options but cannot get anything to work apart of those with jquery/javascript, but I'm sure there's some way to make it work with plain html/css".

Comment: You can't do what you're asking in plain html/css. CSS is for styling, it doesn't have the power to actually DO a lot of things. HTML is for the "structure" of your website, it doesn't have the power to actually DO a lot of things. You can use the `:hover` effect in my answer to get one of the desired results you wanted, but as for the clicking the checkbox on a table row, CSS and HTML are not programming languages and do not have logic to them. You will have to use javascript/jQuery to do it. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm gonna auto-answer because I've managed to make it with plain html+css...it seems that you don't know what those languages are capable of.

Comment: I just want to add a bit more, HTML+CSS is more efficient than javascript, and much more efficient than Jquery. The problem is that isn't too straight forward as Jquery is.

Comment: You'd have to write a huge website like facebook before you would notice anything related to efficiency. I'm glad you were able to answer your question with html/css, but you could have saved yourself hours of time. Kudos to you though!

Comment: Actually is what I'm building, a two years project by myself ;) , anyway is always good to learn the right way to do things if you have the time for it.